# Comparison between time of 2 DateTime c#

Tags: c#, datetime

What is the best way to compare the time of 2 `DateTime` objects?

For example

- DateTime1 = 2012-07-30 01:00
- DateTime2 = 2012-08-01 02:00

I just need to compare the time NOT the date.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to compare? The difference between the two times?

Comment: You might wanna try to subtract one DateTime from the other one via DateTime2.Subtract(DateTime1) and work with whatever you'd like to compare then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (DateTime1.TimeOfDay > DateTime2.TimeOfDay)
{
    MessageBox.Show("DateTime1 is later");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DateTime.TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) to get just the time part to compare. This is essentially the same as if you did `d - d.Date`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `TimeOfDay` property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx

This gives you the time portion of the value without the date portion.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
TimeSpan ts = d1 - d2;
int totalSecondNumber = ts.TotalSeconds;
```

TimeSpan is a difference between to dates. It gives you properties like TotalSeconds, TotalHours and so on or just Seconds, Hours, etc

Comment: The point is *not* to compare the date part, just the time part.

Comment: This will not ignore the date values though.

Comment: TotalSeconds will not ignore the date part, but Seconds will do.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code using DateTime.TimeOfDay

```
DateTime timeNow = DateTime.Now;
DateTime fromTime = new DateTime(2015, 11, 14, 08, 00, 00);
DateTime toTime = new DateTime(2015, 11, 14, 14, 30, 00);

if (TimeSpan.Compare(timeNow.TimeOfDay, fromTime.TimeOfDay) == 1 && TimeSpan.Compare(timeNow.TimeOfDay, toTime.TimeOfDay) == -1)  
{
}
```

In the above code , if the variable timeNow is between 08:00:00 to 14:30:00 then the condition become true.

```
1 represents time1 > time2
0 represents time1 = time2
-1 represents time1 < time2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to compare the difference between the two times you should use the Timespan object.

By using a Timespan you are able to get the difference in seconds, hours and days etc.

Check out the following for more information:

[Timespan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)